# Mac Rogue Process in Activity Monitor launchd/Installer eating up memory/cpu

Tags: macos, memory

So I have a process called Installer that eats up memory on my Mac OSX 10.9.  It's called "Installer" which makes it hard to Google! Please see image:

[image]

What could this be?  It pops up intermittently and I can't figure out where it's coming from - whats the first steps for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem for the last two days on my iMac and I think it is solved now!

Do the following:

- Look inside: Users/admin/Library/LaunchAgents.

If you see any file with "genieo" in the name, delete it. I found these two:

com.genieo.completer.download.plist

com.genieo.completer.update.plist

- Look inside: Users/admin/Library/Application Support.

If you see any file/folder with "genieo" in the name, delete it. I found this:

com.genieoinnovation.Installer

I was able to track this down by looking in my Activity Monitor application:

[image: Activity Monitor]

This has worked for me. Good luck and I hope this helps.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what it was!  How weird.  Also didn't realise you could only see 'Open Files and Ports' when the process was in action.  I always killed it and then looked at the popup!

Comment: Glad it worked! 
This "Genieo" seems to be installing malware that really hurts performance, at the very least. Who knows what else it might be doing?

Comment: Yea I've no idea how it got installed!